# How to change the look of the "Index Of" page

Tags: html, web, indexing

I am creating a site that allows the person to download the file. The way im doing it now is just uploading the files and folders so if the person wanted something they would go to that folder and download it.
If i wanted to style it like add text how would I do that. If it is done with a html file, i have to create a new .html file for every single file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running apache, you should configure .htaccess files.

check also this : http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/